# How to flip Y axis of pixel data

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

I am learning C++ and after collection The data from glMapBuffer to an array i want to flip the data in y axis

```
unsigned char * Data = (unsigned char *)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 
    GL_READ_ONLY);

   char firstarray[ length * width * 4] ;
   memcpy( firstarray ,  Data , sizeof( firstarray ));
```

Now i want to flip the data of firstarray in y axis.

Comment: If you are using c++, please use `std::vector` or `std::array`

Comment: Be more specific about your intention: The 1920x1080x4 dimension suggests that you want to manipulate a screen buffer. Please add a few more details about the actual task!

Comment: may be with : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill

Comment: @wolf each length value in the new array should store the equivalent  line of the buffer.

Comment: Why not rather `[length][width][4]`? Memory is contiguous anyway...

Comment: It's not clear to me/us what you mean by *equivalent line* - you told nothing about the memory layout within the first (I guess: input) array.

Comment: @Aconcagua in my case the array already has the length firstarray[ length * width * 4]

Comment: Why do you need a mulitdimensional array? You could also write a wrapper function that takes x and y and calculates the index of the 1d-array. If it's just about accessing the array.

Comment: @churill i did try that but i am unable to get the maths right.

Comment: @Wolf i want to flip the buffer in y axis.

Comment: @sums555 You introduced a *second* array of `[length][width*4]`. *That* one should be `[length][width][4]`. Apart from, I'd rather join churill, just skip copying data and have appropriate accessor functions (`f(x, y) = (x * width + y) * 4`), the index operators in the multidimensional array effectively don't do anything else either.

Answer (score 1):

> i did try that but i am unable to get the maths right.

Well, would be far better to get *that* right instead. You actually just produced an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Appropriate accessor functions could look like these:

```
unsigned char* getPixel(unsigned int row, unsigend int column)
{
    return array + (row * width + column) * 4;
}

unsigned char* getSubPixel(unsigned int row, unsigend int column, unsigned int color)
{
    return getPixel(row, column) + color;
}
```

> i want to flip the buffer in y axis

Assuming you want to produced a new image mirrored at x-axis, you can simply

```
std::swap(*getSubPixel(x, y, 0), *getSubPixel(x, width - y, 0))
// same for the other three sub-pixels
// if you decide to return references instead of pointers, you don't need
// to dereference (can skip the asterisks)
```

for each pixel in *half* of the row (must be half, otherwise you'd be swapping all values twice resulting in identical image again) and for each row.

Comment: Can you please show me how can i do this once i have the pixel data.

Comment: void* downsampleData = (unsigned char *)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);

Comment: @sums555 Your `void*` typing is useless, use `unsigned char*` instead, whereas `GL_READ_ONLY` suggests that `const unsigned char*` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @wolf currently i copy this buffer into memcpy(OriginalData, downsampleData, sizeof(OriginalData)); an array , now i want to flip the y axis of the array.

Comment: @wolf i am not able to understand how can that be done.

Comment: @sums555 Please update your question to actually show what you have so far. Currently it's absolutely misleading. If you wish to get it answered, you should not force any potential helpers to collect all the important details from comments themselves. You should also add the [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl) tag.

Answer (score 0):

An array of that size allocated on stack is most likely going to `stack-overflow` (pun intended), so use a vector instead.

Also from the `* 4` (and the dimensions) i think you are using the array to store images, so you can create a struct to store the inner most dimension, like:

```
struct rgba //or color
{ 
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;
};
```

And then create an [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that contains the color struct (`rgba` in my example): `std::vector<rgba> img;`
And you use it like:

```
int length = 1080;
int width = 1920;

std::vector<rgba> img(length * width);

for (int i = 0; i != length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j != width; j++)
        img[i * width + j] = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
```

Or you can take a look at some library that does image processing, example [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)